# Gem needs to append column to passed model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, migration, rails-engines

I cannot find out how to have my gem append a column to an existing model/table. My gem needs to check the `created_at` attribute of a model, and based on time passed, set an `active` column from `true` to `false`. I'm assuming that, upon install, it will end up needing a

```
$ rails {gem_name}:install
```

type call from the terminal to append the active column to the model's table. I don't think that an engine is the way to go because I'm not creating any models in the gem, and the only migration I need is to alter an existing model.

Any links, tutorials or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this issue after posting the question again with a little more information and a little more background.

Please see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884315/creating-rails-engine-gem-to-modify-existing-model-db-table/20886471#20886471)

Basically following the devise gem code base and parsing out what I did and didn't need

Answer (score 0):

It seem you are a beginner. What do you think reading the fine manual on

```
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
```

Comment: Don't be a dillhole. There's a difference between doing rails apps and creating a gem/engine. Clearly you're a beginner with dealing with people

Comment: @Sparkmasterflex i don't know the expression dillhole. but as i read that you try to update with a gem a model in rails i thought you miss quite a lot basics. sorry if i made you angry?

Comment: the Devise gem does this, so I know its possible and maybe even common. now devise is an engine w/ its own routes and such, but it does have the ability to create a model for the actual rails app or append to an existing model.

Comment: @Sparkmasterflex `rails g devise:...` the "g" is missing :)